# PLSQL code stuck ever since i moved one of the inserts outside of the loop

Tags: oracle, plsql

Not 100% sure whether my syntax is correct or not, but newly getting into PLSQL. Right now i have a cursor taking data and I am trying to create just one entry in the Submission table, and then make an entry for every single value i receive after that in Value and Submission_Value. There can only be one submission for every time the stored proc is run but there can be multiple entries correlated to each submission. When I run the stored procedure , it never finishes running but when i put the insert into submission inside of the loop, it ran just fine. Below is my code:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE AGGREGATE_HOURLY IS
  Cursor c1 is
select sum(value_tx) AS sum_of_Values
, v.unit_cd
, v.hr_utc
, v.data_date
, ff.form_field_tx
, ff.form_field_id
, v.hr_num
, v.hr
, s.survey_respondent_id
, vba.entity_id
, vba.acronym
, vba.name
, v.DATA_CODE
, v.utc_offset
, vba.time_zone
, vba.time_zone_offset
, vba.dst_observed
from value v
join submission_value sv on v.value_id = sv.value_id
join form_field ff on sv.form_field_id = ff.form_field_id
join submission s on sv.submission_id = s.submission_id
join survey_respondent sr on s.SURVEY_RESPONDENT_ID = sr.survey_respondent_id
join v_b_a vba on sr.entity_id = vba.entity_id
where form_field_tx = 'D'
group by vba.Entity_id, v.Data_date, v.Hr_num, s.survey_respondent_id, ff.form_Field_tx, ff.form_field_id, v.hr_utc, v.Unit_cd, vba.acronym, vba.name, v.DATA_CODE, v.hr, v.utc_offset, vba.time_zone, vba.time_zone_offset, vba.dst_observed;

  l_var c1%ROWTYPE;
  v_value_id value.value_id%type;
  v_calculation_id calculation.calculation_id%type;
    BEGIN
      OPEN c1;
      FETCH c1 into l_var;
      insert into calculation (calculation_id, survey_respondent_id, calculation_dt, calculation_name_tx, Calculation_Arguments_Tx, create_dt, create_user_id, modify_dt, modify_user_id, effective_dt, inactive_dt, publication_issue_id, entity_survey_id)
                   values (null, get_survey_respondent(0, trunc(sysdate)), sysdate, 'Total_Demand' || sysdate, 'SUM', sysdate, '1', null, null, null, null, null, null)
      returning calculation_id into v_calculation_id;
LOOP
   EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
      insert into value (value_id, energy_product_id, data_source_id, unit_cd, value_tx, utc_offset, data_date, hr_utc, hr, hr_num, data_code, create_dt, create_user_id, modify_dt, modify_user_id, effective_dt, inactive_dt)
      values (null, '1', '2', 'NA', l_var.sum_of_values, l_var.utc_offset, l_var.data_date, l_var.hr_utc, l_var.hr, l_var.hr_num, l_var.data_code, sysdate, '1', null, null, null, null)
                     returning value_id into v_value_id;
 insert into calculation_value (calculation_id, value_id, form_field_id, create_dt, create_user_id, modify_dt, modify_user_id, effective_Dt, inactive_dt)
Values ( v_calculation_id, v_value_id, l_var.form_field_id, sysdate, '1', null, null, null, null);
   END LOOP;
       CLOSE c1;
END AGGREGATE_HOURLY;
```

Comment: Put the `FETCH c1 into l_var`  after the start of  `LOOP`; . You could probably do better with `insert into select *` for the two inserts instead of loop .

Comment: @KaushikNayak please submit your comment as a response so i can give you 'best answer'. i knew that it was something really minor that i was missing, but spent a good few hours stuck on it. thanks again

Comment: Sure I will, just a thing to clarify.. do you need only 1 row to be inserted into `calculation` or all the rows from cursor?

Comment: one row into calculaton, infinite number into the other 2 tables.

Comment: What row will that be? Since you are not ordering by anything in the cursor , `l_var.survey_respondent_id` could be any value returned from the source tables. Which specific one row's value do you want to insert  into `calculation`?

Comment: my survey_respondent_id coming from lvar is incorrect. I am grabbing it using a function that I wrote, i'll have to edit my code. thanks for the catch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is going into an infinite loop because the exit condition

```
c1%NOTFOUND
```

will always be false since you are not fetching any rows inside the `LOOP`.

So, **move** the line `FETCH c1 into l_var` after the start of `LOOP`

`OPEN c1;` may also be placed after the first `insert` (outside loop) for clarity.

Comment: Thank you. i'm going to make the change in my code and see if i captured what you said correctly? would you be able to verify please. the code seems to work... but not sure  if i captued 100% of what you said

Comment: it seems like i need to fetch c1 into l_var for the first insert as well for the insert to work correctly. is that a correct assumption?

Comment: @JohnWick : No..Only inside loop, it is required.

Comment: @JohnWick : Don't change the code in the question. Keep it to the version before your last edit, because now the question wouldn't make sense and will not help the people ending up here with a similar problem.

Comment: sorry ill change it back, was what i had correct though?

Comment: @JohnWick : Why's the confusion still?  `FETCH` is done before you are going to use the columns from it. So, In your case, it could be done only inside the loop. Go through this link https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems020.htm to understand the basics.

Comment: thanks. i was confused because i initially was using a value from the cursor for the insert into the submission table (l_var.survey_respondent_id). If i did need to use a value from the cursor outside of the loop (in the submission insert) i would fetch before that insert correct?

Comment: When i do that, my code gets stuck in an infinite loop again... not sure what im doing wrong...

Comment: @JohnWick : You may ask that as a separate question. It may not be related to the way cursor is fetched. I have already explained several times how open..fetch..loop works and if you have coded correctly it should work.

Comment: yeah you're right, my problem is out of the scope for this question. sorry. i know how it works, just need to figure out some other things i suppose